# JSF valueChangeListener is not called if input box disabled

Tags: jsf

I have an input box comment where valueChangeListener is binded.I am changing my comment input box value and I have some other fields in my form, where for some conditions my comment box getting disabled(expected condition), as this comment box getting disable the valuechangelistner for that comment box is not calling.Is there any way for disabled field also valuechnglistner should fire.

Comment: No, that would defeat the input box being disabled AND jsf checking this serverside and consequently introduce tampering options to end-users.

Comment: Thank You.Do you have any suggestion how this situation can be handled in other way.Actually I need the value in server side though this field disabled.And this is a big form.We are using datamodel to bind the data.only using valuechnglistner we are binding new data.

Comment: **what** value do you need server side? How does it change? Do you change something with javascript? And if it is just disabled and does not change, it will always keep its old (current) value... It looks you are running into an http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Disabled input values are not submitted to server. Use readonly instead. They are submitted to server, but JSF won't process them by default. See duplicate how to force JSF to process them anyway.

Comment: Ouch.... the duplicate is indeed your answer... I keep forgetting this exists/is possible